# Sqoop import from Teradata - No more room in database

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, teradata, sqoop

I am new to Big data, when I am using Sqoop commands to import data from teradata into my Hadoop cluster I am encountering a "No more room in database" error
I am doing the following:

1.The data I am trying to pull into my Hadoop cluster is a **view** table
2.The I have used the following sqoop command

```
 sqoop import --connect "jdbc:teradata://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/DATABASE=XY" \
    -- username user1 \
    -- password xyc
    -- query "
    SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE .... AND \$CONDITIONS \
    " \
    --split-by ITEM_1 \
    --delete-target-dir \
    --target-dir /user/home/folder1 \
    --as-avrodatafile;
```

I know that the default mappers is 4 since I do not have a primary key for my view, I am using split-by.

Using **--num-mappers 1**, works but takes a long time for to port over roughly 36GB of data, hence I wanted to increase the num-mappers to 4 or more, however, I am getting the "no more room" error. Does anyone know what's happening?

Comment: Can you share the exact error log or screenshot? That helps to visualize the problem better.

Comment: Can you share the DDL for your target table in Teradata? Long running jobs and spool/space issues in Teradata are often related to data skewness. Can you modify the DDL of your target table? If so, then you can try defining the Primary Index to a more balance column/set of columns or define it as `NO PRIMARY INDEX` for the time being.